# Application-defined or object-defined error on workbook filepath

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to my open workbook and always receive an `Application-defined or object-defined error`.

`X` is the path for the workbook I want to copy from and `Y` is the path for the workbook I'm in. The error returns on `set = y ...`.

I followed this topic: [Link columns from two different workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411037/link-columns-from-two-different-workbooks)

```
'
' Import data from dump and articles into workbook
'

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FilePath = Range("C2")

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Filename.xlsx")

    'Now, copy what you want from x:
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Value = x.Sheets("articles").Range("A")
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AD:AD").Value = x.Sheets("articles").Range("B")

    'Close x:
    x.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: What line gives you the error. Is FilePath defined as a string? If not it may be getting assigned as a cell based on FilePath = Range("C2"). Define it as a string and do FilePath = Range("C2").Value

Comment: I get the error at `Set y = ...` Filepath isn't defined as a string. Inside cell C2 I have the following `C:\path\filename.xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("A")` and `Range("B")` are not proper ranges:

```
    Range("A").Select   'this generates an error
```

.

Try this (tested)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyWorkBookDataColumns()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ur1 As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet, ur2 As Range, lr2 As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook 'already open (file running current VBA code)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\FileToOpen.xlsx")

    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("articles")    'copy to this Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")      'copy from this Worksheet

    Set ur1 = ws1.UsedRange                 'copy to this Range
    Set ur2 = ws2.UsedRange                 'copy from this Range

    lr2 = ur2.Row + ur2.Rows.Count          'last row in file2

    'copy from ws2 to ws1
    ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr2).Value2 = ws2.Range("B1:B" & lr2).Value2
    ws1.Range("B1:B" & lr2).Value2 = ws2.Range("AD1:AD" & lr2).Value2

    wb2.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Note: `...Range("B:B")=...Range("A:A")` will waste resources by copying 1 million+ values

Comment: I tried your code, but now get an `Object doesn't support this method or object error`. Any suggestions? (i feel like an idiot, but it's been so long ago >.<)

Comment: My mistake: `Worksheet(...)` should be `Worksheets(...)`. I fixed it, ran the code, and it works - please try it again

Comment: now it changed error to Subscript out of range on ws1

Comment: it worked by using `Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook` as `Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have posted the actual code that you are having issues with, your issue is most likely that \username\ is not an actual directory.  You will need to make that either hard coded to the actual name you are logged into the workstation with(if it is only going to be run by you) or make it dynamic for whomever is logged in.

If your login is jsmith your desktop path would be.

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\FileToOpen.xlsx")
```

To make it dynamic you will want to get the username from the system. Assuming you are using Windows:

```
Dim strUserName As String
strUserName = Environ$("Username")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & strUserName  & "\Desktop\FileToOpen.xlsx")
```

That handles the username, you will also have to change \FileToOpen.xlsx to the actual name of the Excel workbook you are wanting to open. Ex. \Inventory.xlsx

NOTE: Some windows domains are setup so the user directory is username.domain. So if your domain is CORP your directory could be jsmith.CORP.

If the above is not the problem you could try this.

```
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\jsmith\Desktop\FileToOpen.xlsx")
```

I have seen it done that way.

Answer (score -1):

MatthewD's comment is correct, and you also have a similar issue with each of the lines where you're doing the copying. Look's like you're not referencing the ranges or their values correctly. Also, I strongly recommend using Value2 instead of Value. Value2 is the one that returns the same result you would get if you used an Excel formula to set x = y, while Value truncates certain data. Almost certainly not a feature you want.

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Value2 = x.Sheets("articles").Range("A:A").Value2
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AD:AD").Value2 = x.Sheets("articles").Range("B:B").Value2
```

Lastly, if these fixes don't resolve your issue, it would be extremely helpful if you could indicate which exact line of code triggers the error.